# Castle Windsor: How do I inject all implementations of interface into a ctor?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I've written an interface which is implemented by multiple classes. I want to write a Service class which will have all the registered implementations injected into its ctor.

The only solution I can think of is to call the Service Locator within the ctor and ask it to Resolve() all implementations.

Ideally I would like something like this -

```
interface IVehicle
{
    void Start();
}

class Car : IVehicle
{
    public void Start()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Car started.");
    }
}

class Truck : IVehicle
{
    public void Start()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Truck started.");
    }
}

class Motorbike : IVehicle
{
    public void Start()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Motorbike started.");
    }
}

class VehicleService
{
    // How do I inject all implementations of IVehicle?
    public VehicleService(IEnumerable<IVehicle> vehicles)
    {
        foreach (var vehicle in vehicles)
        {
            vehicle.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT** - I should mention I'm using Castle Windsor.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You have to use `CollectionResolver`. Check this [Castle Windsor FAQ](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/faq.md):

> Windsor, by default when you have dependency on IFoo[],
>   IEnumerable or IList will check if you have a component
>   registered for that exact type (array or list of IFoo), not if you
>   have any components registered for IFoo (array of components, is not
>   the same as a component which is an array). You can change the
>   behavior to say "When you see array or list of IFoo just give me all
>   IFoos you can get" you use CollectionResolver.

Direct link to Castle Resolvers: [Resolvers](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/resolvers.md).

Answer (score 33):

I know this has already been answered, but I thought an example of how to add the CollectionResolver would be useful, so here it is.

Call AddSubResolver before registering the components in the container, e.g.

```
container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new CollectionResolver(container.Kernel));
```

Register the components as normal:

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<IVehicle>().ImplementedBy<Car>(),
    Component.For<IVehicle>().ImplementedBy<Truck>(),
    Component.For<IVehicle>().ImplementedBy<Motorbike>()
);
```

Comment: Great example. In case anyone gets the "Handler for System.Collections.Generic.List`1[IFoobar] was not found."} error message, this could be caused by a constructor requiring an implemented ICollection instance, such as public FoobarConstructor(List<IFoobar> ifoobarImplementations), but should be public FoobarConstructor(IEnumerable<IFoobar> ifoobarImplementations)

Answer (score 22):

Found this answer useful though I was still missing how to register all the implementations of a given interface.

Hope this helps!

```
container.Register(
            Classes.FromAssemblyContaining<IVehicle>()
                .BasedOn<IVehicle>().WithService.FromInterface()
            );
```

Comment: This simply cannot be the accepted answer because it's solving something different but it's very helpful. In combination with the accepted answer it's a clean solution.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. After registering `VehicleService` with `container.Register(Component.For<VehicleService>().ImplementedBy<VehicleService>())`, I replace manual registration (`Component.For<IVehicle>().ImplementedBy<Car>()`) with `Classes.FromAssemblyContaining<IVehicle>()                    .BasedOn<IVehicle>().WithService.FromInterface()`, which causes an exception when I do `container.Resolve<VehicleService>()`: "Blah blah blah... 'WindsorTest.Program+VehicleService' is waiting for the following dependencies: - Service '....IEnumerable`1[[...]]' which was not registered."

Comment: I posted this up nearly 5 years ago; the project has been through 2 major versions since then.

Give this example a go with version 3.3.0 and see if it works; this should tell you if its an issue on your side or a breaking change in Castle Windsor.

Comment: Also check the answer below - are you adding the sub resolver line? 

container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new CollectionResolver(container.Kernel));

Comment: Yes, I'm adding `CollectionResolver` before registering. I found the problem: It only works if the classes are marked `public` (in Windsor 5.0.1) (note that OP's classes weren't public)

Answer (score 4):

The answers here are all correct but I just wanted to add a little extra wrinkle to it: You have to add the sub-resolver **BEFORE** you register your components.

This will work:

```
container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new CollectionResolver(container.Kernel));
container.Register(
    Component.For<IVehicle>().ImplementedBy<Car>(),
    Component.For<IVehicle>().ImplementedBy<Truck>(),
    Component.For<IVehicle>().ImplementedBy<Motorbike>()
);
```

This will **NOT** work

```
container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Register(
    Component.For<IVehicle>().ImplementedBy<Car>(),
    Component.For<IVehicle>().ImplementedBy<Truck>(),
    Component.For<IVehicle>().ImplementedBy<Motorbike>()
);
container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new CollectionResolver(container.Kernel));
```

Comment: Registering the interface implementations (re: CountZero) should also be done after the AddSubResolver call.

Comment: How to define CollectionResolver, when registration done in configuration xml file?