# dependency injection : how to refactor a ugly if-else-if block

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, refactoring, ninject, castle-windsor

I have a class which is able to call differents payment services such as Paypal, Payline and others depending on the attributes values of the main argument (a Payment object) :

```
public class PaymentExecutor
{
    IPaymentProcessor fooProcessor;
    IPaymentProcessor barProcessor;
    IPaymentProcessor bazProcessor;
    IPaymentProcessor quxProcessor;

    public PaymentExecutor(...)
    {
        fooProcessor = new FooProcessor(...);
        barProcessor = new BarProcessor(...);
        bazProcessor = new BazProcessor(...);
        quxProcessor = new QuxProcessor(...);
    }

    public Payment Execute(Payment payment)
    {
        IPaymentProcessor processor;

        if (payment.Channel == "foo" && payment.Some = thing
            && (payment.Foo == bar || payment.Bar == foo))
        {
            processor = fooProcessor;
            // ...
        }
        else if (azerty == b && c == d && e.UseCase.IsIn("a", "b", "c", "d"))
        {
            processor = barProcessor;
            // ...
        }
        else if (azerty == g && h == i && k.UseCase.IsIn("g", "h"))
        {
            processor = bazProcessor;
            // ...
        }
        else if (azerty == b && c == d && e.UseCase.IsIn("u", "i", "p")
                 && somethingElse == "foobar")
        {
            processor = quxProcessor;
            // ...
        }

        return processor.Process(payment);
    }
}
```

This code has been very simplified and a little prepared for DI (the interfaces, actually we are using inheritance).

I'm new to DI (I already used Ninject and Castle Windsor and I can't see how to replace/refactor this big ugly if-else-if block using DI.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `if` `else` block isn't a problem that DI is intended to solve. The purpose of DI is to have objects explicitly identify and declare the dependencies that they require in order to function properly, so that they can be provided with said dependencies instead of creating them on their own.

For example, `PaymentExecutor` is dependent on a set of `IPaymentProcessor` objects, but creates these objects. To support DI, `PaymentExecutor` can be refactored to accept these payment processors as parameters to its constructor, rather than create them directly. Like this:

```
public PaymentExecutor(IPaymentProcessor fooProcessor, IPaymentProcessor barProcessor, IPaymentProcessor bazProcessor, IPaymentProcessor quxProcessor)
{
    this.fooProcessor = fooProcessor;
    this.barProcessor = barProcessor;
    this.bazProcessor = bazProcessor;
    this.quxProcessor = quxProcessor;
}
```

All that being said, you can still refactor the `if` `else` block into something more maintainable (DI just doesn't enter into it).

The logic currently residing in the `if` statements might be breaking the encapsulation of the individual payment processors. That is, `PaymentExecutor` is making a decision about whether or not a particular payment processor is able to actually process a payment. **This decision might best be left to the processors themselves.**

For example, consider if the `IPaymentProcessor` interface declared the following method:

```
    bool CanProcessPayment(Payment payment);
```

The conditional logic could then be refactored into the individual processors:

```
class FooProcessor : IPaymentProcessor
{
    // ...

    public bool CanProcessPayment(Payment payment)
    {
        return payment.Channel == "foo" && payment.Some == thing
            && (payment.Foo == bar || payment.Bar == foo);
    }
}
```

... and out of the `PaymentExecutor`:

```
class PaymentExecutor
{
    // ...

    public Payment Execute(Payment payment)
    {
        if (fooProcessor.CanProcessPayment(payment))
        {
            return fooProcessor.Process(payment);
        }
        else if (barProcessor.CanProcessPayment(payment))
        {
            return barProcessor.Process(payment);
        }
        // ...
}
```

**Edit:** At this point, you can see that `PaymentExecutor` technically doesn't even care what types of payment processors it contains. (It only cares about finding a processor that is capable of processing a payment.)

Instead of forcing `PaymentExecutor` to use 4 arbitrary payment processors, what if we allowed it to use any number of processors? For example:

```
class PaymentExecutor
{
    IEnumerable<IPaymentProcessor> processors;

    PaymentExecutor(IEnumerable<IPaymentProcessor> processors)
    {
        this.processors = processors;
    }

    public Payment Execute(Payment payment)
    {
        foreach(var processor in processors)
        {
            if(processor.CanProcessPayment(payment))
            {
                return processor.Process(payment);
            }
        }
        // Handle what should happen if no processors can process the payment...
}
```

This version of `PaymentExecutor` is arguably more expressive, but more importantly it plays much more nicely with DI Containers. Now, instead of having to figure out how to tell the DI Container to resolve 4 arbitrary payment processors, you tell it how to resolve a collection of payment processors.

More details on this can be found in this answer:

[Castle Windsor: How do I inject all implementations of interface into a ctor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452155/castle-windsor-how-do-i-inject-all-implementations-of-interface-into-a-ctor)

Comment: I like it. But how can I resolve the four interfaces ?
I mean, how the dependency injector knows which implementation of the interface go to such-and-such constructor argument ?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include some additional details on how you would get this to work with a DI Container. (Let me know if it doesn't make sense.)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the accepted answer, but I want to present an alternative approach I have used in the past to good effect. It takes a little more setup but provides good benefits in the long run.

Note: code below elides all error checking, excuse any typos, etc.

Let's say we can add a `PaymentType` enum to the solution :

```
public enum PaymentType
{
    Foo=0,Bar,Baz,Qux
}
```

You could then create an interface `IPaymentTypeDecider`

```
public interface IPaymentypeDecider
{
    PaymentType DeterminePaymentType(Payment payment);
}
```

and implement it with the logic you have for deciding what payment type to use:

```
public class PaymentTypeDecider: IPaymentTypeDecider
{
   public PaymentType DeterminePaymentType(Payment payment)
   {
      PaymentType result = PaymentType.Foo; //e.g default option
      if
      {
         //your complex logic here based on payment
      }
      return result;
   }
}
```

> My rationale for this is to keep to logic of what payment type to use separate from the actual executor. This will help to keep the code of `PaymentExecutor` simpler, as well as allowing you to test the logic for deciding on the payment method to use in isolation from `PaymentExecutor`.

Next, you define a set of empty marker interfaces, one for each payment type, that inherits from `IPaymentType`:

```
public interface IFooPaymentProcessor:IPaymentProcessor{}
public interface IBarPaymentProcessor:IPaymentProcessor{}
public interface IBazPaymentProcessor:IPaymentProcessor{}
public interface IQuxPaymentProcessor:IPaymentProcessor{}
```

and implement them:

```
public class FooPaymentProcessor: IFooPaymentProcessor
{
    //implement it.
}....etc.
```

> Note: the reason for the marker interfaces is because this is how I learned how to do it; its quite possible that the auto-factory generation of many IOC frameworks can do a lot of this solution for your already (although I am not so sure they can do the custom dictionary-based factory above).

Next, within the scope of your Composition Root (example assumes you are using `Ninject` but this will work for any IOC framework), you create an interface and implementation for a `PaymentProcessor` factory:

```
public interface IPaymentProcessorFactory
{
    IPaymentProcessor GetProcessor(PaymentType paymentType)
}

public class PaymentProcessorFactory
{
    readonly IKernel _kernel;
    Dictionary<PaymentType,IPaymentProcessor> _processors;
    public PaymentProcessorFactory(IKernel kernel)
    {
        //save the kernel for later use
       _kernel=kernel;
       //register our payment processors for given PaymentTypes
       _processors = new Dictionary<PaymentType,IPaymentProcessor>()
       {
          {PaymentType.Foo,typeof(IFooPaymentProcessor)},
          {PaymentType.Bar,typeof(IBarPaymentProcessor)},
          {PaymentType.Baz,typeof(IBazPaymentProcessor)},
          {PaymentType.Qux,typeof(IQuxPaymentProcessor)}
       }
    }
    public IPaymentProcessor GetProcessor(PaymentType paymentType)
    {
        //pop the Payment Type from the dictionary, and resolve via kernel:
        return _kernel.Get(_processors[paymentType].Value) as IPaymentProcessor;
    }
}
```

> This factory class is just acting like a "lazy resolver" for IOC, in that it will only ever produce `IPaymentProcessors`, but only when its asked to by your code, not automatically. This means you can pass context to it (`PaymentType` in this case) and get back the correct implementation at runtime.

And then wire up all your bindings:

```
_kernel.Bind<IPaymentTypeDecider>().To<PaymentTypeDecider>();
_kernel.Bind<IPaymentProcessorFactory>().To<PaymentProcessorFactory>();
_kernel.Bind<IFooPaymentProcessor>().To<FooPaymentProcessor>();
_kernel.Bind<IBarPaymentProcessor>().To<BarPaymentProcessor>();
_kernel.Bind<IBazPaymentProcessor>().To<BazPaymentProcessor>();
_kernel.Bind<IQuxPaymentProcessor>().To<QuxPaymentProcessor>();
```

Finally you refactor your `PaymentExecutor` class to take a dependency on `IPaymentTypeDecider` and `IPaymentProcessorFactory`:

```
public class PaymentExecutor
{
   readonly IPaymentTypeDecider _decider;
   readonly IPaymentProcessorFactory _factory;

   public PaymentExecutor(IPaymentTypeDecider decider, IPaymentProcessorFactory factor)
   {
       _decider=decider;
       _factory=factory;
   }

   public Payment Execute(Payment payment)
   {
      var paymentType=_decider.DeterminePaymentType(payment);
      var processor = _factory.GetProcessor(paymentType);
      return processor.Process(payment);
   }   
}
```

Major advantages of this approach that I see are

- Excellent decoupling of dependencies; you can easily mock the dependencies on your `PaymentExecutor` class for testing
- Ability to add a new payment type without having to modify `PaymentExecutor` at all (you just create the interface, update the decider logic, register in the factory class /bindings, and you're good to go).
- Adding the payment processors individually as constructor parameters means if you end up with 20 processors (who knows!) it will get messy, not to mention you are also going to be creating an instance of every single payment processor type each time you create a `PaymentExecutor`.

Hope that helps.